# VHDL one if holds true in every case and the other doesn't

Tags: button, if-statement, vhdl, store

The ssd process that follows this is to show me what I have for the both users. The code atm seems to store the data for both users perfectly well and also recall it in any given time. However the problem is that I cannot seem to change the fact that whenever I press either of the buttons -to increase or decrease the number hold in either user by the decimal 1-. It changes the first user's number no matter what. It does not matter if the switch(7) is '1' or '0'. Additionally I can select the second user, although I cannot make any change on him as well -the buttons only affect the first user-. Here is my problem and I do not have any clue why this happens, but my only intuition is that I have a terrible design right here. Anyway below is the code for the interested and the helpful:

```
process (clk)

begin

    if(switch(7) <= '1') then --first user

        if(rising_edge(clk)) then
            if(btn(0)='1' and lastButtonState(0) = '0') then--increase by 1
                user0 <= user0 + "001";
            end if;
            lastButtonState(0) <= btn(0);
            if(btn(1) = '1' and lastButtonState(1) = '0') then --decrease by 1
                user0 <= user0 + "111";
            end if;
            lastButtonState(1) <= btn(1);
        end if;



    elsif (switch(6) = '1') then --second user
        if(rising_edge(clk)) then
            if(btn(0) = '1' and lastButtonState(0) = '0') then
                user1 <= user1 + "001";
            end if;
        lastButtonState(0) <= btn(0);

            if(btn(1) = '1' and lastButtonState(1) = '0') then

                user1 <= user1 + "111";

            end if;
            lastButtonState(1) <= btn(1);
        end if;


    end if;


end process;
process (user0, user1, switch)
begin

    if(switch(7) = '1') then
        case user0 is
            when "000" => a_to_g <= "0000001";
            when "001" => a_to_g <= "1001111";
            when "010" => a_to_g <= "0010010";
            when "011" => a_to_g <= "0000110";
            when "100" => a_to_g <= "1001100";
            when "101" => a_to_g <= "0100100";
            when "110" => a_to_g <= "0100000";
            when others => a_to_g <= "0001111";
        end case;


    elsif (switch(6) = '1') then
       case user1 is
           when "000" => a_to_g <= "0000001";
           when "001" => a_to_g <= "1001111";
           when "010" => a_to_g <= "0010010";
           when "011" => a_to_g <= "0000110";
           when "100" => a_to_g <= "1001100";
           when "101" => a_to_g <= "0100100";
           when "110" => a_to_g <= "0100000";
           when others => a_to_g <= "0001111";
       end case;

    end if;
end process;
```

Comment: That code has several problems. However the specific one causing trouble at the moment is probably that you don't actually test if Switch 7 = '1'. Less than or equals, yes. Equals, no.

Comment: What is an ssd process? solid-state-drive or seven-segment-display? Please don't use non-common abbreviations.

Comment: You can also label any statement in VHDL, including process statements.  Which of the two processes are considered ssd? What is a 'code atm'? Your two processes don't comprise a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Some hints for this piece of code:

- Your code describes gated clocks - that's no good coding style!
  Put every thing inside `if rising_edge() then` (exception: asynchronous resets)
- You could remove one 7-seg. decoder block, if you divide your second process in a mux and a decoder:

  ```
  process (user0, user1, switch)
    variable temp : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
  begin
    if(switch(7) = '1') then
      temp  := user0;
    elsif (switch(6) = '1') then
      temp  := user1;
    else
      temp  := "000";
    end if;

    case temp is
      when "000" => a_to_g <= "0000001";
      when "001" => a_to_g <= "1001111";
      when "010" => a_to_g <= "0010010";
      when "011" => a_to_g <= "0000110";
      when "100" => a_to_g <= "1001100";
      when "101" => a_to_g <= "0100100";
      when "110" => a_to_g <= "0100000";
      when others => a_to_g <= "0001111";
    end case;
  end process;
  ```
- I would suggest to extract the rising edge detection on your button signals from your main process. Edge detection is a signal pre-processing step and should be decoupled from control-logic. If you are doing a edge detection: Have you synchronized and debounced your signals?

  ```
  -- edge detection in 2 lines
  btn_d  <= btn when rising_edge(clk);  -- delay (*_d) all button signals for one cycle
  btn_re <= not btn_d and btn;          -- calculate rising edge (*_re) strobe signal for every button
  ```
- Why don't you use the minus operator to subtract 1 instead of adding -1 ?

## Edit 1 regarding comment 1:

I assume you are using a standard elaboration board equipped with (push) buttons and (sliding/dip) switches.

First of all, every external asynchronous signal must be synchronized to the internal clock of the design to prevent meta stability issues. This is normally done by implementing a double flip flop synchronizer (2 D-FF as a chain, no shift registers).

```
-- example for a Xilinx ML505 board
port map (
  -- ...
  ML505_GPIO_Button_CPU_Reset_n  : in  STD_LOGIC;
  ML505_GPIO_Button_West         : in  STD_LOGIC;
  ML505_GPIO_Button_East         : in  STD_LOGIC;
  ML505_GPIO_Switches            : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
);

-- signals
architecture ...
  -- signals to convert low-active signals to high-active
  signal ML505_GPIO_Button_Reset : STD_LOGIC;

  -- signals for double synchronization
  signal GPIO_Buttons_async    : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 downto 0);
  signal GPIO_Buttons_meta     : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 downto 0)  := (others => '0');
  signal GPIO_Buttons_sync     : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 downto 0)  := (others => '0');
  signal GPIO_Buttons          : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 downto 0);
  signal GPIO_Buttons_d        : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 downto 0)  := (others => '0');
  signal GPIO_Buttons_re       : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 downto 0);

  signal GPIO_Switches_async   : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
  signal GPIO_Switches_meta    : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0)  := (others => '0');
  signal GPIO_Switches_sync    : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0)  := (others => '0');

-- ...
begin
  -- source code to pre process external signals
  -- =============================================
  -- convert low-active signals to high-active
  ML505_GPIO_Button_Reset <= ML505_GPIO_Button_Reset_n;

  -- input synchronization
  GPIO_Buttons_async(0)  <= ML505_GPIO_Button_Reset;
  GPIO_Buttons_async(1)  <= ML505_GPIO_Button_West;
  GPIO_Buttons_async(2)  <= ML505_GPIO_Button_East;
  GPIO_Switches_async    <= ML505_GPIO_Switches;

  -- double FF synchronizer
  GPIO_Buttons_meta  <= GPIO_Buttons_async  when rising_edge(Clock);
  GPIO_Switches_meta <= GPIO_Switches_async when rising_edge(Clock);

  GPIO_Buttons_sync  <= GPIO_Buttons_meta  when rising_edge(Clock);
  GPIO_Switches_sync <= GPIO_Switches_meta when rising_edge(Clock);
```

The next step is to debounce the signal, because many boards don't use bounce-free components (this can be done mechanically, by a simple capacitor or a external debounce circuit). So If you are not sure or your board has no debounced user inputs, you have to implement a certain circuit by yourself. Debouncing meens, that your signal is stable for at least the debounce duration. This time can be 5 ms.

```
deb1 : entity PoC.io_Debounce
  generic map (
    ports  => 3
  )
  port map (
    Clock  => Clock,
    Input  => GPIO_Buttons_sync,
    Output => GPIO_Buttons
  );
```

A debounce circuit is just a filter to suppress glitches. The result is a 'flag' signal (long periods of high or low).

In most cases user inputs are feed into FSMs or whatever. These circuits need strobe signals (high-active logic: high impulse for one cycle). This 'conversion' can be done by an edge detection (rising or falling).

```
-- edge detection
GPIO_Buttons_d  <= GPIO_Buttons when rising_edge(Clock);
GPIO_Buttons_re <= not GPIO_Buttons_d and GPIO_Buttons;

-- final renaming after pre processing
GPIO_Button_Reset <= GPIO_Buttons_re(0);
GPIO_Button_West  <= GPIO_Buttons_re(2);
GPIO_Button_East  <= GPIO_Buttons_re(1);
```

Now you can use the pre processed signals in your circuits.

## Appendix:

The line `a_d <= a when rising_edge(Clock);` is a short form for a simple D-FF without enable and reset. Alternatively you can use a standard process. The line `a_re <= not a_d and a;` is a check for `a` was zero and is now one -> rising edge condition. See me other posts for more details on one-liner flip flops. [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27229600/vhdl-short-form-to-trigger-actions-on-raising-edges/27230228#27230228)

Comment: The idea about the 7-seg. is wonderful! I did not think about that. I will definitely implement it.
I got a one question though. Can you elaborate more on "extracting the rising edge detection on your button signals from my main process", because I did not understand the button code that you wrote and the debouncing, because the buttons work as is?

Comment: @Briandrummond I do not think I get your point. Doesn't this clause -if(switch(7) = '1') then- check whether the switch(7) is on or off? And if it is 1 then it proceeds to execute the code following. Am I mistaken? To clarify my problem, switch(7) executes the code below anyway regardless of the input of switch(7) and the surprising thing is that I have the exact same coding for the second user -switch(6)- which does not work.

Comment: @royalgobbal : "Doesn't this clause -if(switch(7) = '1') then- check whether the switch(7) is on or off?" Yes. But the code in your question is different.

Comment: Upvoted because this is a good answer, but more importantly it never occurred to me that you could do `btn_d <= btn when rising_edge(clk);` to infer a flop in a single line.

Comment: @QuantumRipple Originally it's a solution of a classmate. Noone beliefed him! But it works! I just extended his idea to other FF types by using functins. It's also possible to write a counter function. Have a look for this file, it's my complete component package: https://code.google.com/p/picoblaze-library/source/browse/vhdl/lib_PoC/components.vhdl?name=release